# What are the sizes of individual cells of the cyanobacterium Nostoc spheroides?

Tags: bacteriology

In [this article](https://sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1002007108002815) [Nostoc spheroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nostoc_commune_var_spheroides) are described as edible blue-green algae, but they are mostly named cyanobacteria, which are prokaryotes.

In the above and other articles about Nostoc spheroids only sizes of the colonies are mentioned and i couldn't find the individual cell sizes.

Can the sizes of individual cells of Nostoc spheroids, and other cyanobacteria like Nostoc commune and Nostoc muscorum be found somewhere on the internet ?

Comment: We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: @tyersome  If you read my question well, i did some research. I thought this is a very straight forward question. It's not my fault if it can't be answered !

Comment: 1) You may have done some research, but IMO posting a link to Wikipedia page notifying us that there is no such page isn't convincing. 2) Lack of interest in searching out trivia for you isn't a sign that the question can't be answered. ——— If you really care about this information I encourage you to either write a convincing argument for why this is interesting or spend the time to find out the answer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a question about a bacterial species. Bergey's manual is your friend: it is the definitive manual for bacterial morphology. Most universities have it as a pdf —I am unable to speculate on whether it is also available on say sci-hub (a paper pirating site). Check out figure 810.78 on page 576. Their shape can vary a large bit, but it is in the 1-3 µm range, so the usual size for diderm bacteria (2 µm is the length of an *E. coli*).